# Why OpenCV has no specialize data structure for region?

Tags: opencv, structure, space

I have been using MVTec's Halcon Image Processing Library for half a year and OpenCV for 1 year.

**1. One thing I found that Halcon much outperforms OpenCV is that OpenCV has no specialize data structure for region.**

This is lots of waste if I only want to store a small region in a large space. Shouldn't OpenCV have some specialized data structure for region other than Mat Class.

**2. Second one, which is the result of the previous one, is that OpenCV is awkward to iterate through regions.**

Imagine the scenario that I have 10 connected blocks of region after doing threshold and I want to iterate through that 10 blocks to process each of them. As far as I know, I have to first use findContours to get all the contours of each region and then I use drawContour to get that region. So can I say that the regions is stored by the contour data and each time I want to get the region back I have to call drawContours?

```
Mat myImage = imread("Path_To_Source_Image");
threshold(myImage, region, 128, 1, THRESH_BINARY);
vector<vector<Point>> contours;
findContours(region, contours, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
for (int i = 0; i < contours.size, i++){
    Mat oneBlock(myImage.size(), CV_8U); 
    drawContours(oneBlock, contours, i, Scalar(255), -1);
        // Now I finally get my region

        //  ***************************************
        //
        //   Do my image procesing for that region
        //
        //  ***************************************
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately I dont have Halcon experience. Can you explain better what regions are? Are they some kind of sub-images or more like sparse pixel locations? What kind of processing is possible on regions? From my understanding/intuition, the combination of subimages and masks could be regions.

Comment: "and each time I want to get the region back I have to call drawContours?" - why not just remember the result of drawContours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common approach to represent regions is to use a `Mat1i` (aka a `Mat` of type `CV_32S`) that contains the indices of the regions, i.e. the `labels`.

You can then access the i-th region simply with: `Mat1b region_mask = (labels == i);`

With OpenCV < 3.0, you can use `findConturs` and `drawContours` to create the `labels` image:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Read image from file 
    Mat1b img = imread("path_to_image", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    Mat1b region;
    threshold(img, region, 200, 255, THRESH_BINARY);

    vector<vector<Point>> contours;
    findContours(region.clone(), contours, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    Mat1i labels(img.rows, img.cols, int(0));
    int n_labels = contours.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); ++i)
    {
        drawContours(labels, contours, i, Scalar(i + 1), CV_FILLED); // Note the +1, since 0 is the background
    }

    // Now you can get your regiones as:

    // Label "0" is the background
    for (int i = 1; i <= n_labels; ++i)
    {
        Mat1b region_mask = (labels == i);
        imshow("Region", region_mask);
        waitKey();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

With OpenCV >= 3.0 you can use `connectedComponents`, which will directly return the `labels`:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Read image from file 
    Mat1b img = imread("path_to_image", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    Mat1b region;
    threshold(img, region, 200, 255, THRESH_BINARY);

    Mat1i labels;
    int n_labels = connectedComponents(region, labels);

    // Now you can get your regiones as:

    // Label "0" is the background
    for (int i = 1; i <= n_labels; ++i)
    {
        Mat1b region_mask = (labels == i);
        imshow("Region", region_mask);
        waitKey();
    }

    return 0;
}
```