# OpenCV - getConnectedComponents errors

Tags: c++, opencv

I was writing code and I need to use function to finde connected components but I got two errors :

Error   7   error LNK2005: "int __cdecl getConnectedComps(struct _IplImage *,int &,class std::vector > &)" (?getConnectedComps@@YAHPEAU_IplImage@@AEAHAEAV?$vector@PEAUCvConnectedComp@@V?$allocator@PEAUCvConnectedComp@@@std@@@std@@@Z) already defined in main.obj   C:\Users\Kristina\Desktop\Kompjuterska vizija\PrviProjekat\PrviProjekat\getConnectedComps.obj   Domaci1

Error   8   error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found   C:\Users\Kristina\Desktop\Kompjuterska vizija\PrviProjekat\x64\Debug\Domaci1.exe    Domaci1

What is the problem?I have been using MicrosoftVisualStudio 2013, and functions

getConnectedComps.h

```
#include "opencv/cxcore.h"
#include "opencv/cv.h"
#include "opencv/cvaux.h"
#include "opencv/highgui.h"

#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int getConnectedComps(IplImage *image, int &totalComps,      vector<CvConnectedComp*> &components);
```

getConnectedComps.cpp

```
#include "getConnectedComps.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

#define MAX_COMPONENTS 250

int getConnectedComps(IplImage *image, int &totalComps, vector<CvConnectedComp*> &components)
{
    int width, height;

    if (!(image->roi))
    {

        width = image->width;
        height = image->height;
    }
else
{

    width = image->roi->width;
    height = image->roi->height;
}


vector<CvConnectedComp*>::iterator itComponent = components.begin();
int currentCompValue = 0;

for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        CvScalar pixval = cvGet2D(image, y, x);


        if (pixval.val[0] > currentCompValue)
        {

            if (++currentCompValue > MAX_COMPONENTS)
                return -1;


            if (*itComponent == NULL) *itComponent = new CvConnectedComp;


            cvFloodFill(image,cvPoint(x, y), cvScalar(currentCompValue), cvScalar(0), 
                cvScalar(0), (*(itComponent++)), 8);
        }
    }


totalComps = currentCompValue;
return 0;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "opencv2/videoio/videoio.hpp" 
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <vector>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "getConnectedComps.cpp"
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv){

vector<CvConnectedComp*> components;
VideoCapture video1;
int vektor,s;
int width, height, frames1, fps1;
video1.open(argv[1]);
fps1 = video1.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
width = video1.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
height = video1.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
frames1 = video1.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);

cout << "Video1 " << argv[1] <<
    ": width=" << width <<
    ", height=" << height <<
    ", frames=" << frames1 <<
    ", fps1=" << fps1 << endl;


int i = 0;
int j = 0;




Mat frameTime2, frameForeground, frameForeground1,maska, frameForeground2, frame3[3],frameForeground3, frameForegroundOut1, frameForegroundOut2;

Mat frameTime1(height, width, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0, 0, 0));

while (1){

    video1 >> frameTime2;
    bool bSuccess = video1.read(frameTime2);
    if (!bSuccess) //if not success, break loop
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Cannot read a frame from video file" << endl;
        break;
    }
    absdiff(frameTime1, frameTime2, frameForeground);
    split(frameForeground, frame3);
    threshold(frame3[0], frameForeground1, 15, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
    threshold(frame3[1], frameForeground2, 15, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
    threshold(frame3[2], frameForeground3, 15, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
    bitwise_or(frameForeground1, frameForeground2, frameForegroundOut1);
    bitwise_or(frameForegroundOut1, frameForeground3, maska);
    frameTime2.copyTo(frameTime1);
    morphologyEx(maska, frameForegroundOut2, MORPH_OPEN, Mat());
    erode(frameForegroundOut2, frameForegroundOut2, Mat());
    morphologyEx(frameForegroundOut2, frameForegroundOut2, MORPH_CLOSE, Mat());
    morphologyEx(frameForegroundOut2, frameForegroundOut2, MORPH_OPEN, Mat());
    dilate(frameForegroundOut2, frameForegroundOut2, Mat());
    dilate(frameForegroundOut2, frameForegroundOut2, Mat());
    dilate(frameForegroundOut2, frameForegroundOut2, Mat());
    dilate(frameForegroundOut2, frameForegroundOut2, Mat());
    morphologyEx(frameForegroundOut2, frameForegroundOut2, MORPH_CLOSE, Mat());
    morphologyEx(frameForegroundOut2, frameForegroundOut2, MORPH_CLOSE, Mat());
    morphologyEx(frameForegroundOut2, frameForegroundOut2, MORPH_CLOSE, Mat());
    morphologyEx(frameForegroundOut2, frameForegroundOut2, MORPH_CLOSE, Mat());
    IplImage* img = new IplImage(frameForegroundOut2);
    getConnectedComps(img, vektor, components);
}
```

}

Comment: **Don't use obsolete C api**.  Forget about `getConnectedComp`, is just useless. You can get connected components like in [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36935370/5008845)

Comment: That works thanks!But I have one more question, because this is the part of one project, after I get connected components I need to rectangle all connected components larger than 160 pixels. How can I proceed this labels file to it ?