# drawContours fails to create a correct mask in OpenCV 3.1.0

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I want to split the characters of an Image using OpenCV in order to train a Tesseract model.

I am using version **3.1.0** (because of a Macports upgrade - *meh..*), and the documentation (for Python) is still not very clear/well-documented.

Here is what I do:

1. Binarize the Image in order to be ready to find the contours
2. Find the contours *(which works - at least I get non-zero results)*
3. For each contour:

   1. Create a mask *(this probably fails - gets zeros)*
   2. Extract the part from the original image using the mask *(should work but the mask fails, so this doesn't work yet)*

The new version of OpenCV has somewhat different syntax as well, so this makes it even more tricky sometimes.

Here is my code:

```
def characterSplit(img):
    """
    Splits the characters in an image using contours, ready to be labelled and saved for training with Tesseract
    """

    # Apply Thresholding to binarize Image
    img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (3,3), 0)
    img = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 75, 10)
    img = cv2.bitwise_not(img)

    # Find Contours
    contours = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL , cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_TC89_KCOS, offset=(0,0))[1]

    # Iterate through the contours
    for c in xrange(len(contours)):
        mask = numpy.zeros(img.size)

        cv2.drawContours(mask, contours, c, (0, 255, 0), cv2.FILLED)    # Mask is zeros - It might fail here!

        # Where the result will be stored
        res = numpy.zeros(mask.size)

        # Make a Boolean-type numpy array for the Mask
        amsk = mask != 0

        # I use this to copy a part of the image using the generated mask.
        # The result is zeros because the mask is also zeros
        numpy.copyto(res, img.flatten(), where = amsk)

        ## (... Reshape, crop and save the result ...)
```

As far as I know, the mask should be of the same size as the original image. But should it also have the same shape? For instance, my image is 640x74 but the way I create my mask matrix, my mask is 1x47360. Maybe this is why it fails... *(but doesn't throw any errors)*

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You should use `cv::connectedComponents`. [it'll be easier.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36935370/5008845)

Comment: Ok I didn't know about `cv::connectedComponents`. I will give it a try

Comment: @Miki Ok, I played around with connectedComponents, but it doesn't give the result I need. In my case, it can detect the background, but I want to split the characters. So, each character should be one region/label. Is it possible to be done with connectedComponents?

Comment: Ah! Nevermind! If I threshold the image with Gaussian (as I did originally) then it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing what Miki proposed in the comments. I used `cv::connectedComponents` to do the character splitting. Here is the corresponding code, for anyone who is interested:

```
def characterSplit(img, outputFolder=''):
    # Splits the Image (OpenCV Object) into distinct characters and exports it in images withing the specified folder.

    # Blurring the image with Gaussian before thresholding is important
    img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (3,3), 0)
    img = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 75, 10)
    img = cv2.bitwise_not(img)

    output = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(img, 8, cv2.CV_16S)
    n_labels =  output[0]
    labels = output[1]
    stats = output[2]

    for c in xrange(n_labels):
        # Mask is a boolean-type numpy array with True in the corresponding region
        mask = labels == c

        res = numpy.zeros(img.shape)
        numpy.copyto(res, img, where=mask)

        # The rectangle that bounds the region is stored in:
        # stats[c][0:4] -> [x, y, w, h]

        cv2.imwrite("region_{}.jpg".format(c), res)
```

Hope this helps!